# How to register a client side script in a static web method?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, static-methods, client-side-scripting

I want to register a client side script in a static web method. Here is my codes:

```
 public static class ScriptRegister
 {
    public static void RegisterScript(Page page, string script)
    {
        page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Refresh", script, true);
    }
 }
```

I use this class to register client side scripts.

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static void UpdateCartCount(int prodId, int count)
    {
            ...
             ScriptRegister.RegisterScript(this.Page,script);
    }
```

As you know, I can not use ***this*** in a static method. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: How are you calling the UpdateCartCount method?